# Enabling RDP in all workgroup computers

Tags: windows, windows-xp, rdp

I need to activate RDP on all our Windows XP Computers who are currently in workgroup mode.. anyone knows a script or a software that can scan / activate the RDP Service on the machines?

I've already have a script that does part of it.. the main problem is the running of the script on all computers...

I have administrator access to all of them... but running one by one is a bit of a trouble :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the script you currently have? This sounds like a job for PSExec (Sysinternals). The main regkey you need is:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\fDenyTSConnection

Which should be changed to 0. Though that depends on if it was explicitly disabled originally, and how.

Personally, I'd make a script for PSExec which copies a .reg fragment over and then logs the change to a text file centrally on a server.

You could also use something like "Reg.exe" which I think is on XP, but I don't have a station to hand to test.

Serious question - why are you using computers in a Workgroup rather than a domain?

Comment: The workgroup is being remodeled to a domain but in various sites it's not implemented yet.. I have that reg key as a script yes.. what I really wanted was some kind of software that ran in a range of ips and executed that command!

Comment: Then look at PSExec or reg.exe as I explained.

Comment: Dan but psexec only runs in a pc at a time that will gonna make me run it on every pc on the network individually

Comment: It will only execute on one PC at a time, yes, but the whole point is that it's remotely executed. I.e., you create a text file with all of your machines and create a batch script to go down them and run your command on each PC.

There are lots of examples on Google for this.